# Adding subtotals from HTML input and adding them with Javascript without Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add specific inputs from my HTML template and add them using javascript. I have reached the part where I can add all the inputs with `('[type="number"].form-control')` but I want to be able to specifiy the inputs by ID so that I can have different subtotals.

here is a print screen of what I want to acheive:
[image]

I want to add Item 1 and Item 2 and get a subtotal. Add Item 3 and 4 and 5 and get subtotal. Then add the 2 subtotals together.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    <script>
    const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);
    const qa=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);
    const results={};

    qa('[type="number"].form-control').forEach(input=>input.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
      /* add the value against the id to the object described above */
      results[ this.name ]=Number( this.value );

      if( Object.keys( results ).length==2 ){
        q('th#Total').textContent=[ ...Object.values( results ) ].reduce((a,v)=>a+v);
      }
    }));
    </script>
<!-- language: lang-html -->
                <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap table-borderless">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Type in the Equipment and assets"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="item_1"
                          id="item_1"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_1.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_1.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <h6 style="float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-top:7px">$</h6>
                        <input
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="number"
                          class="form-control w-25"
                          name="item_1_amount"
                          id="item_1_amount"
                          style="float:left"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_1_amount.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_1_amount.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Type in the Equipment and assets"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="item_2"
                          id="item_2"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_2.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_2.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <h6 style="float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-top:7px">$</h6>
                      <input
                        autocomplete="off"
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control w-25"
                        name="item_2_amount"
                        id="item_2_amount"
                        style="float:left"
                        {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_2_amount.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                        {% for err in form.item_2_amount.errors %}
                          <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <thead class="table-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">subtotal</th>
                      <th scope="col" id="Total"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Type in the Equipment and assets"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="item_3"
                          id="item_3"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_3.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_3.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <h6 style="float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-top:7px">$</h6>
                        <input
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="number"
                          class="form-control w-25"
                          name="item_3_amount"
                          id="item_3_amount"
                          style="float:left"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_3_amount.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_3_amount.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Type in the Equipment and assets"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="item_4"
                          id="item_4"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_4.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_4.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <h6 style="float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-top:7px">$</h6>
                      <input
                        autocomplete="off"
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control w-25"
                        name="item_4_amount"
                        id="item_4_amount"
                        style="float:left"
                        {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_4_amount.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                        {% for err in form.item_4_amount.errors %}
                          <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Type in the Equipment and assets"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="item_5"
                          id="item_5"
                          {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_5.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                          {% for err in form.item_5.errors %}
                            <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <h6 style="float:left; margin-right:5px; margin-top:7px">$</h6>
                      <input
                        autocomplete="off"
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control w-25"
                        name="item_5_amount"
                        id="item_5_amount"
                        style="float:left"
                        {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.item_5_amount.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                        {% for err in form.item_5_amount.errors %}
                          <small class="text-danger mb-2 ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <thead class="table-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">subtotal</th>
                      <th scope="col" id="Total2"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <thead class="table-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Grand Total</th>
                      <th scope="col" id="Grandtotal"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-primary mt-5"
                      onclick="stepper1.previous()"
                    >
                      Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-5">
                      Submit
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

My question:
How to add Item 1 and 2 together to get Subtotal 1 then add 3 and 4 together to get subtotal 2 and then add the 2 subtotals to get the grand total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spun a codepen of the code I'm about to explain here (with comments in the JS as well): https://codepen.io/marcusparsons/pen/vYZrVpy?editors=1010

The best way to achieve that kind of functionality is to group your inputs together with a couple more binding classes. What I did was add an extra primary class and then a subset class for targeting groups so that way individual groups can be calculated dynamically (meaning you could have any amount of inputs in a group and each value will be taken into account without extra code). And also, they each have a primary class because we're also getting a Grand Total.

For example, you want to add item 1 and item 2 together for Subtotal 1. Well, you could do that manually, but I always ask the question, "What if I have 1,000 inputs I want to equal Subtotal 1?" In this case, classes come in super handy, like so (I stripped some of your server side code to be able to work with just the HTML and JS needed):

```
<input
                        autocomplete="off"
                        type="number"
                        <!-- Added subtotal-group and subtotal-group-2 class -->
                        class="form-control w-25 subtotal-group subtotal-group-2"
                        name="item_4_amount"
                        id="item_4_amount"
                        style="float:left">
```

Basically, item 1 and item 2 got the `subtotal-group` and `subtotal-group-1` classes. And then items 3, 4, and 5 got the `subtotal-group` and `subtotal-group-2` classes.

And then, in the JavaScript, I target each of the groupings and apply them to the target elements you want.  I also changed the event keyword to `input` from `keyup` because if you only target `keyup` on a `type="number"` input, you will miss the events that occur when up and down arrows are clicked/touched and you'll miss copy/paste events from user. When in doubt, I go with `input` over `keyup` for the event to listen to.

```
//Gather totals for subtotal-group-1 which is item 1 and item 2
//you could expand this ad infinitum by adding input type=number elements to the class subtotal-group and subtotal-group-1
//Keeping these elements grouped together with these classes allow us to be flexible and group things together
//Classes are powerful!!!
const resultGroupSet1 = [...qa('.subtotal-group-1')]
                              .map(s => Number(s.value))
                              .reduce((a,v) => a+v);
      q('th#Total').textContent = resultGroupSet1;
```

And then rinse and repeat for each subsequent group:

```
const resultGroupSet2 = [...qa('.subtotal-group-2')]
                              .map(s => Number(s.value))
                              .reduce((a,v) => a+v);
      q('th#Total2').textContent = resultGroupSet2;
```

And to get the final group total, just target the primary `.subtotal-group` class:

```
const resultGroupSetGrandTotal = [...qa('.subtotal-group')]
                              .map(s => Number(s.value))
                              .reduce((a,v) => a+v);
      q('th#Grandtotal').textContent = resultGroupSetGrandTotal;
```